# Passing All Directories To Express Using Nginx

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I'm trying to pass through all the directories in my app through to express, and in some cases directories that contain a dynamic 'key' which I'll :capture.

I can't get even a defined sub-directory, /pretest, to pass through to express. Despite copying the the same options for Location /, it serves me an Ngxin 404

Ideally, I want domain.com/prepop/{lookup_key} to pass to localhost:8080/prepop/{lookup_key}

Where {lookup_key} is a different value each time

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? Any/all help is much appreciated.

Code-

server.js

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const cors = require("cors")

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

const app = express();

app.use(cors())

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    res.send('hello');
    
});

app.get('/pretest', (req, res) => {

    res.send('test');
    
});

app.get('/prepop/:lookup_key', (req, res) => {

    let connection = mysql.createConnection({
 //commented out for stackoverflow
    });

    connection.connect();

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM table_incoming_leads WHERE leadid = '+req.params.send_key, (err, response, fields) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);

        res.json({
            email: response[0].email,
            first_name: response[0].first_name,
            last_name: response[0].last_name
        })
    });

    connection.end();


        


    

})



app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`));
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {


    root /var/www/html;



    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;       
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /pretest {

        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;               
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

    location /prepop {

        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;               
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = subdomain.mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name subdomain.mydomain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `try_files` directive from `/prepop` location because when nginx receives a request for let's say `/prepop/somekey` it looks for a file with that name (`somekey`) in your root directory. Since there is no such file it returns 404.

Comment: Good point - I removed it. However, it's still giving me a 404 error. Even when I navigate to /pretest (this was setup strictly for debugging).

Do you see anything wrong with the /pretest config?

Comment: I have just noticed that you proxy_pass every location. Remove try_files from them and see if it works.